# How to serve continuously updating page with Jetty Server?

Tags: java, jetty, server

I try to deploy a html page that is being updated continiously to Jetty server. I place it under webapps/project/index.html . On the terminal Jetty Logs show that the content is AVAILABLE and then UNAVALIABLE for small gaps. Here is the output

```
2015-05-01 19:30:50.898:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@287d8a36{/project,file:path_to/Libs/jetty/webapps/project/,UNAVAILABLE}{/project}
2015-05-01 19:30:50.956:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Scanner-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@2b29af8b{/project,file:path_to/Libs/jetty/webapps/project/,AVAILABLE}{/project
```

Due to this circulation, I cannot reach the content from the browser.

Is there any way to config Jetty for such a updating content?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have your webapp setup to hotdeploy on changes.

Deploy it once, don't test with development based deployment, don't test with jetty-maven-plugin, don't use jetty-runner, don't set hotdeploy up (set the `scanInterval` to 0 to not detect updates).

Downside is that if you change the metadata of the webapp (any content in `WEB-INF`) then it will not redeploy.

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer, but I am not confident for Jetty. How can I apply these configurations to my app.